# AJAX: hidden field in GET method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I clik on image which have id="voteinc" I call this function, and I get this  message in Chrom:

```
http://localhost/PSI/Dokumentacija/Faza5/Implementacija/votes/voteAlg?incdec=inc&alg=9&a=addcomment&_=1400260139619
```

I don't know where it appeared the fourth parameter, the GET method sends 3 parameters.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#voteinc").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        async: false, 
        url: $("#ratesection").attr('action'),
        data: {
            incdec: $("#voteinc").attr('value'),
            alg: $("#algcode").attr('value'),
            a: $("#addcomment").attr('id')
        },
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        success: function(mess) {
            console.log(mess);
            if(mess=='voted') {
                alert("Glasali ste vec!");
            } else if (mess=='error') {
                alert("Problem sa bazom");
            } else {
                $("#algRate").val(mess);
            } 
        }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The added parameter is jQuery's 'cache-buster' and is used to bypass caches that are between the originator (you) and the source url. Since you have set cache to false, jQuery is appending the cache buster for you

[See jQuery AJAX documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: +1 From the doc: `[Cache] works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.`

Comment: but i never saw this fourth parameter, by default cache is true??

Comment: Yes! from the jQuery API: `cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp').`